# how to set datetime Value for extjs textfield?

Tags: javascript, datetime, extjs, textfield, setvalue

There is an array of `items`:

```
items: [{
  fieldLabel: 'Username:',
  id: 'usernameID',
  readOnly: true,
  value: user.username,
  name: "username"
}]
```

I need to set the date time value to this text field:

```
Ext.getCmp('usernameID').setValue(Fromdate);
```

In from date I get value of datetime. But while setting I am getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setValue' of undefined

Comment: Try `itemId: 'usernameID'` instead of `id: 'usernameID'` or: `Ext.getCmp('[name=username]')`

Comment: Preferentially use datefield instead of textfield. xtype:datefield, value: new Date().Take a look at http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.0/api/Ext.form.field.Date.html

Answer (score 1):

You don't have xtype defined in your items. Are you using the default xtype for the items? Is your textfield or anything even rendered?

This code is functional:

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    id: 'myCustomId',
    fieldLabel: 'Label',
    name: 'username',
    value: 'something',
    readOnly: true
}, {
    xtype: 'button',
    handler: function (button, e) {
        var cmp = Ext.getCmp('myCustomId');
        cmp.setValue(Ext.Date.format(new Date(), 'Y-m-d'))
    },
    text: 'Set the value'
}]
```

Check out fiddle 
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1m7f

In case this does not help you post more parts of your code.

Answer (score 0):

First define the type of your object with the `xtype` property. After that you need to get the `date` you want to set. In this example I used the *ExtJS* `datepicker` to get the date, but you can also use `new Date()`.
Once the date has been obtained you need to format it with the `format` function, and then `set` your object with this formatted value. In this example I used two formats `Y-d-m` (Year, Month and Day) and`d-m-Y` (Day, Month and Year). For more information on format access [this link](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.Date).

To test in other versions of ExtJS access [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1m7g).

```js
   Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    title: 'Set Date',
    closable: false,
    width: 500,
    layout: 'vbox',
    bodyStyle: 'padding: 5px;',
    items: [{xtype: 'container',
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox',
                align: 'stretch'
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: 'datepicker',
                minDate: new Date(),
                bodyStyle: 'padding-left: 50px;',
                handler: function(picker, date) {
                    Ext.getCmp('txtDate1').setValue(Ext.Date.format(date, 'Y-m-d'));
                    Ext.getCmp('txtDate2').setValue(Ext.Date.format(date, 'd-m-Y'));
                }
            }, {
                xtype: 'container',
                    layout: {
                        type: 'vbox',
                        align: 'stretch'
                    },
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        fieldLabel: 'Date 1:',
                        labelAlign: 'right',
                        id: 'txtDate1',
                        width: 200
                    }, {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        fieldLabel: 'Date 2:',
                        labelAlign: 'right',
                        id: 'txtDate2',
                        width: 200
                    }]
            }]
        }]
}).show();
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.0/ext-all.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.0/resources/css/ext-all.css")/>
```